# v-for rendering children of each object in separate div - preventing .sort

Tags: vue.js

I have come across the following `"bug"` in `vue-3`;

Before I explain, here is my data structure/hierarchy;

```
export const datatwo = [
{id: "1", artist: "Yaakov Shwekey", dateadded: "07/04/2022", artistroute: "/yaakovshwekey", 
albums: [{album:'Shomati', songsinalbum: [
        { song : 'MaMaMa', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, 
        { song : 'Al Naharos Bavel', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]},  
        { song : 'Levinyomin', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, ]},   

        {album : 'Simcha', songsinalbum: [
            { song : 'Kolot', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]}, 
            { song : 'Kalu Kol Hakotzim', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]},  
            { song : 'Vehi Sheamdah', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]}, ]},   ]
},
{id: "2", artist: "Baruch Levine", dateadded: "07/04/2022", artistroute: "/baruchlevine", 
albums: [
    {album : 'Vezkani', songsinalbum: [
        { song : 'Vezakani', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, 
        { song : 'Bitchu', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]},  
        { song : 'Vhu', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, ]},   

        {album : 'Touched by a Niggun', songsinalbum: [
            { song : 'Faultche Phony Rebbe', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]}, 
            { song : 'Tour of Yerushalayim', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]},  
            { song : 'Someones Child', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]}, ]},   ]
},
{id: "3", artist: "Simcha Leiner", dateadded: "10/04/2022", artistroute: "/simchaleiner", 
albums: [
    {album : 'Simcha Leiner One', songsinalbum: [
        { song : 'Mi Mi Mi', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, 
        { song : 'Veal Hakol', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]},  
        { song : 'Shalom', keys: [
            {key: "Am"},
            {key: "Em"}
        ]}, ]},   

        {album : 'Simcha Leiner Two', songsinalbum: [
            { song : 'Mi Adir', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]}, 
            { song : 'Boi Kallah', keys: [
                {key: "Am"},
                {key: "Em"}
            ]},  
            ]},   ]
}
]
```

Now, what I wish to do is to display all of the `album` names in a alphebetical list without the use of a `computed property`, rather just by creating a `v-for` in a `v-for`. The reason for this is since I require access to the `artist` name for the `router`.
So this is the `v-for` loop I have created (with the sort function attached to the second loop(even though I know that it is not best for performance!));

```
  <div v-for="(itemone) in datatwo" :key="itemone.id">
                <div class="" v-for="(itemtwo) in itemone.albums.sort((a, b) => (a.album > b.album) ? 1 : -1)" :key="itemtwo.album">
                    <router-link class="routerlink" :key="itemtwo.songsinalbum" :to="'/albumselected/' + itemtwo.album + '/artist/' + itemone.artist">
                        <div class="routerlink button">{{itemtwo.album}}</div>
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, the sort does not work properly, since the way `vue` renders child objects is by creating separate divs for each parent, and naturally the `.sort` function does not work.
This is how `Vue` renders the above `v-for`;

```
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Shomati/artist/Yaakov Shwekey" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Shomati</div>
            </a></div>
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Simcha/artist/Yaakov Shwekey" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Simcha</div>
            </a></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Touched by a Niggun/artist/Baruch Levine" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Touched by a Niggun</div>
            </a></div>
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Vezkani/artist/Baruch Levine" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Vezkani</div>
            </a></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Simcha Leiner One/artist/Simcha Leiner" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Simcha Leiner One</div>
            </a></div>
        <div class=""><a href="/albumselected/Simcha Leiner Two/artist/Simcha Leiner" class="routerlink">
                <div class="routerlink button">Simcha Leiner Two</div>
            </a></div>
    </div>
```

The computed property I have been using is;

```
sortedSongs() {
        const res = []
        this.datanew.forEach(data => {
            data.albums.forEach(album => {
                res.push(album)
            })
        })


        return res.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.album > b.album) return 1
            else return -1
        })
    },
```

Does anyone in the open source community have a solution to this? Would really appreciate help or validation!

Comment: It's a mistake to call sort in the template as it mutates the array, not to mention it's called on each render. Preprocess `datatwo` to match your requirements. "he reason for this is since I require access to the artist name for the router" - I don't see how it's related,  `datatwo` could be a computed and still used the same way

Comment: Hi, thank you so much in your interest. How could is still possibly use artist in the router while using a computed property? Could you possibly share a snippet or answer? I can add what I have done, but it don't have access to the artist. thanks a ton

Comment: You didn't specify which computed property. If it's `datatwo`  that were a computed with sorted data, it would be used exactly the same way as it currently is, with the exception of `sort` in the template. 
Please, clarify what the problem is. I can't help at this point because it's unclear what's going on in the component and where `datatwo` comes from, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . As I said, it could be preprocessed, so it could be used as is without sorting.

Comment: Again I wish to create a list of all the albums in all of the objects and display this a-z. However, if use sort in a computed property I won't have access to the artist names which I require for the route, since the only way I can think of doing a sort on the albums is by doing the following , which leaves me no access to the artist?

Comment: am editing answer to add the computed property.

Comment: edited, sorry. tried to send link but was too long!

Comment: Just make the same structure as original datatwo in a computed, but with sorted data. and always call sort on array copy, `datatwo.map(item => ({...item, albums: [...item.albums].sort(...) }))`

Comment: could you possibly add this as an answer, don't properly understand how to implement this. would really appreciate thanks

Comment: or even just edit my current computed property

Comment: It's implemented exactly the way the comment lists, the code is ready to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mistake to call `sort` in the template as it mutates the array, not to mention that it's called on each render.

It can be the same structure as original `datatwo` in a computed, but with sorted data:

```
sortedData() {
  return datatwo.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    albums: [...item.albums].sort((a, b) => { /* ... */ })
  }))
}
```

Or to sort and use `albums` as a single list:

```
sortedData() {
  return this.datanew.flatMap(item => item.albums.map(album => ({
    ...item,
    ...album
  })))
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.album > b.album) return 1;
    else if (a.album < b.album) return -1;
    else return 0;
  });
}
```

And used the same way, but without `sort` in the template.

`sort` should be called on array copy to avoid mutation.

Comment: this does not work. would appreciate it you would fix it up!

Comment: It's unknown why it doesn't work for you and what not work actually means. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem as requested previously

Comment: It does not work, since when I try v-for{{ item.album}} it renders nothing! And when I v-for {{item}} it renders each object in a separate div!

Comment: There's no `item.album` in the code you posted. There's itemtwo.album. I can't help without seeing the whole code. You asked about how to add a computed, and the post shows how. `sortedData` will behave the same way as `datatwo`, with no sorting issues.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. here is a Stackblitz of it https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xk2h9c?file=src/App.vue

Comment: In your example it's `datanew` state and not `datatwo` constant. Once you replace `datatwo` with `this.datanew`, and replace `datanew` with `sortedData` in the template, it's workable, https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-j24uxd

Comment: Sorry for some reason it hadn't saved, please have a look again. have done that all and it doesn't work, commented it!. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I'm probably such a pain!

Comment: you can edit the code if you want.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xk2h9c?file=src/App.vue

Comment: It's forked when saved, https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fef5jy?file=src/App.vue . Notice that you need to use -1, 1 and 0 in sort function in order for it to work correctly. And it's preferable to sort strings with localeCompare. Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks, though I still can't seem to be able to render all the album names in the v-for? it is just empty? thanks

Comment: could you possibly have one more look to sort that out. that I am able to render {{item.album}} sorted using your computed property? thanks so much

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-uujxuw?file=src/App.vue

Comment: Given that data, it should be as in previous example. Item has `albums`, which is an array, not `album`. If you have other problems with rendered data besides the one that was originally posted, consider asking new questions, so others users could give the best possible answers.

Comment: Hi, that is my original question! Please help! I need a access to the artist and album as posted in original question. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. It's done like shown here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fef5jy?file=src/App.vue . `albums` is an array and needs to be iterated with its own v-for. You didn't specify in the question what is the desired output. If you need to display sorted and ungrouped list of albums, you need to flatten it, it's done with flatMap like shown here https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-1q15s5?file=src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I wanted! You brilliant!

Comment: last disturbance... how could I render all the "song", i.e., a child in a child in a child on the same project stackblitz.com/edit/vue-1q15s5?file=src/App.vue. thanks so much

Comment: You'll need to use nested v-for

Comment: thanks. just did a flatmap in a flatmap. you've been amazing